# SQL Join Query -

Tags: sql

I need perform a join where:

1. I am only interested in pulling all person ID's where one of the IDs contains the value 'N'
2. Then I need to perform a join that will return the name of the IDs

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried (if any)?

Comment: What did you try until now?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: One thought

Comment: This is a terrible title for a question.  Take a read: [ask].

Comment: Ya sorry it is badly worded, I will read the link provided @rory.ap

Comment: Got there thanks - select 
 perId.PersonId, 
 perId.Identifier, 
 pn.Name, 
  from PID perId
  inner join
  (
   select distinct PersonId
   from PID
   where Identifier like 'N%' 
  ) as PersonIdsWithId ON perId.PersonId = PersonIdsWithId.PersonId
  left join sol.PersonName pn on perId.PersonId = pn.PersonId
  order by perId.PersonId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will helps

```
Select per.personId,per.name ,idn.identifier from 
person per inner join idetifier idn on (idn.personId = per.personId and 
idn.identifier like '%N%')
```

Comment: This returns only the rows with the N identifer.  That is not what the question specifies.

Answer (score 0):

A `join` brings in the person name.  That is trivial.  You can use `exists` to get the people whose identifier starts with an `N`:

```
select i.*, pn.name
from identifier i join
     personname pn
     on i.personid = pn.personid
where exists (select 1
              from identifier i2
              where i2.personid = i.personid and
                    i2.identifier like 'N%'
             );
```

Comment: didnt end up using this but seems like it would of worked - thanks

Answer (score 0):

select Identifier.*,Person.PersonId,Person.Name from Identifier inner join on Identifier.PersonId=Person.PersonId;